# Regexp to match only n occurrences of a char in a string

Tags: regex, kde4

I have a string like `2005:10:29 12:23:53` and I wish to replace only first two occurrences of `:` with `-`

Expected result `2005-10-29 12:23:53`

EDIT:

I need this regexp in KDE's `krename` tool, where I can't edit/format the original `[exifExif.Image.DateTime]` witch returns the unwanted `2005:10:29 12:23:53` format, but there is a `Find and Replace` to post process the String

`(?<=\d{4}):|:(?=\d{2}\s)` does the job [on rubular](http://rubular.com/), but does not in KDE :(

I am sure there are more solutions.

EDIT:

`:(?=\d{2}:\d{2}\s)|:(?=\d{2}\s)` works even on KDE

I find this solution after I read

```
You can use a full-fledged regular expression inside the lookahead.
Most regular expression engines only allow literal characters and
alternation inside lookbehind, since they cannot apply regular
expression backwards.
```

in [Regex tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: so what language do you want to use? You just removed JavaScript and Ruby...

Comment: I think you'd better ask krename support: http://www.krename.net/Mailinglist.14.0.html

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby, as scibuff suggests, you're probably better not using Regexps.

```
require 'date'
date = DateTime.parse("2005:10:29 12:23:53", "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")
date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Sorry for confusing tags I removed them (javascript, ruby) +1 for ruby solution.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript:

Version 1

```
str = str.split(' ')[0].replace(/\:/g,'-')+' '+str.split(' ')[1]
```

Version 2

```
str = str.replace(/(\d{4}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})(.*)/,"$1-$2-$3 $4")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Pu7ju/)

Comment: Sorry for confusing tags I removed them (javascript, ruby)

Comment: +1 works fine in JavaScript and nice to know about DEMO link :)

Answer (score -1):

Once again using regular expressions for something that can be achieved in a simpler, more elegant and more efficient way

```
var date = new Date('2005:10:29 12:23:53');
```

then format `date` accordingly, e.g.

```
function formatDate( date ){

    return date.getFullYear() + '-' + ( get.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + ... ;

}
```

Comment: That would be wonderful if the Date function allowed yyyy:mm:dd hh:mm:ss - but it doesn't. So you need to first change the first set of : to - which is what OP wanted to know how to do

Comment: Sorry for confusing tags I removed them (javascript, ruby)

Answer (score -1):

Simply call `replace()` twice:

```
"2005:10:29 12:23:53".replace(/:/,'-').replace(/:/,'-')
```